# Issue with Deleting Object in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've unlimited arrow object ...

```
local function deleteit(obj)
  display.remove(obj)
end

local function createArrow()
  local arrow = display.newImageRect("images/right",64,64)
  arrow.x = centerX
  arrow.y = centerY
  transition.to(arrow,{time = 1000, x = 0 , y = 0 , onComplete = deleteit(arrow)})
end

timer.performWithDelay(1000,createArrow,0)
```

But when I run this game, all of my arrow vanish. I know why they vanished but I don't know how to fix this code. Please help me.

PS. I cannot use array because of memory problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you assign the callback for **onComplete** you are actually calling the **deleteit** function and therefore you are deleting the object before the timer expires.

The callback wants a reference to a function, but you are actually calling the function instead of just getting a reference.

Try this:

```
local function createArrow()
   local arrow = display.newImageRect("images/right",64,64)
   arrow.x = centerX
   arrow.y = centerY

   local cb = function()
     deleit( arrow )
   end

   transition.to(arrow, {time=1000, x=0, y=0, onComplete=cb} )
end
```

Comment: I have another question. Could you help me pleaseeeee http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761950/issue-with-priority-when-objects-overlap