# Issue with Priority when objects overlap

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have 2 object Object1 and Object2

When I use

```
transition.to(Object1,{time=1000,x=Object2.x,y = Object2.y})
```

Object1 will be above Object2. If I want Object2 to be above Object1, how can I do?

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [object:toFront](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/toFront.html) to move Object2 to front.

Something like this:

```
Object2:toFront()
```

Note: this not only moves Object2 in front of Object1 but in front of all other siblings.
If you want more control about displaying you need to built it yourself :)